# Combine multiple files to one sheet as values and remove filters

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I would like to combine sheets with the same name & format from multiple files into a single summary sheet. I used this code to do it but I found it won't copy any filtered data or link cells. I also tried a couple codes to remove the filter, and the copied data becomes uncontinuous. Could someone look into this and help me? Thanks!

```
Sub Multiple_to_One()
Dim MyPath, MyName, AWbName
Dim Wb As Workbook, WbN As String
Dim G As Long
Dim Num As Long
Dim BOX As String
Dim lo As ListObject
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
MyName = Dir(MyPath & "\" & "*.xlsm")
AWbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Do While MyName <> ""
    If MyName <> AWbName Then
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & MyName)
          With Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet
            Wb.Sheets(13).UsedRange.Copy .Cells(.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
            Wb.Close False
        End With
    End If
    MyName = Dir
Loop
MsgBox "All done.", vbInformation, "bingo"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I set the autofiltermode to False. This worked in my case.
`Wb.Sheets(13).AutoFilterMode = False`

Here is the modified code.

```
Sub Multiple_to_One()
    Dim MyPath, MyName, AWbName
    Dim Wb As Workbook, WbN As String
    Dim G As Long
    Dim Num As Long
    Dim BOX As String
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    MyPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    MyName = Dir(MyPath & "\" & "*.xlsm")
    AWbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    Do While MyName <> ""
        If MyName <> AWbName Then
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & "\" & MyName)
        Wb.Sheets(13).AutoFilterMode = False

        ThisWorkbook.Activate
          With Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet
            Wb.Sheets(13).UsedRange.Copy .Cells(.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
            Wb.Close False
        End With
    End If
    MyName = Dir
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "All done.", vbInformation, "bingo"
```

End Sub

Comment: The spreadsheet needs to be copied has many columns categorized into "name", "depth","elevation""state parameter" and "Soil Unit". So these are on the first row of the spreadsheet and all the data below these titles has been filtered. Some data has been hidden due to the soil unit filter setting. I would like to copy all the data including those hidden from soil unit filter, and paste all 151 similar excel files into a summary sheet.

Comment: You should use comments on the OP to ask for clarifications.

Comment: Well, I tried to be nice and undo it, even though the answer is not useful as is. (Thus the original downvote.) But, unfortunately, it has been too long. The system does not let me remove it now. If you edit your answer and make it more useful, it should let me undo it.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hopefully this is better :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a brute force method, but seems to work:

```
Sub Summarize()
    Dim sourcePath As String
    Dim sourceName As String
    Dim sourceWorkbook as Workbook  ' Workbook to be copied
    Dim sourceSheet as Worksheet
    Dim thisWorkbookName as String
    Dim copyCell as Range
    Dim sourceBase as Range         ' Summary starts here

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    sourcePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    thisWorkbookName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    sourceName = Dir(MyPath & "\" & "*.xlsm")
    Set sourceBase = Workbooks(1).ActiveSheet.Range("A1")  ' Set to what you want

    Do While sourceName <> ""
        If sourceName <> thisWorkbookName Then
            Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourcePath & "\" & sourceName)
            Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Sheets(13)
            For Each copyCell In sourceSheet.UsedRange
                copyCell.Copy sourceBase.Offset(copyCell.Row - 1, copyCell.Column - 1)
            Next
            Set sourceBase = sourceBase.Offset(sourceSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
            Set copyCell = Nothing
            Set sourceSheet = Nothing
            sourceWorkbook.Close False
        End If
        sourceName = Dir
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox "All done.", vbInformation, "bingo"

End Sub
```

I'm just manually copying every cell in the used range into the target sheet. The base cell gets reset after each sheet, so it should just keep appending to the target sheet.

**Caveat**

I've only tested the inner code in my own sheet. I made adjustments on the fly to fit everything into your original logic. The entire function above should replace your original function. If you have errors, it's because I mistyped something. My apologies.